# How do I retrieve Spring Data's PersistentEntity?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

In an aspect around a `JpaRepository`s `save()` method I'm trying to check if the entity to be saved is new or exists already and should be updated.

I have noticed that [Spring Data REST uses the `isNew()` method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java#L361) of the `PersistentEntity` class but have not found how I could possibly get ahold of a `PersistentEntity` object while only having the model class of the entity that is to be created or updated.

How do I retrieve Spring Data's `PersistentEntity` object from the entity that is to be stored or updated?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify more?

Comment: Do you need to use an aspect instead of using for example an entity interceptor?

Comment: @YCF_L Maybe elaborate more on what you did not understand?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm not sure, have not yet heard of entity interceptors. I could use `RepositoryEventHandler`s from Spring Data REST, but those only trigger when the change has gone through Spring Data REST. But I also want to capture calls of `repository.save()` from other places. The `PersistentEntity` object of that concerned entity seemed the easiest.

Comment: @Daniel there are a lot of different mechanisms, so I suggest looking around to see which fits your requirements best.

Comment: @Kayaman The method through the PersistentEntity would be best I think, but I cannot find any documentation on how to retrieve it.

Comment: @Daniel why do you think so? You haven't even checked all the other possibilities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206213/discussion-between-daniel-and-kayaman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just inject a `Repositories` instance and obtain the `PersistentEntity` from that:

```
@Component
class SomeComponent {

  private final Repositories repositories;

  SomeComponent(Repositories repositories) {
    this.repositories = repositories;
  }

  void someMethod(Object someEntity) {

    PersistentEntity<?> entity = repositories.getPersistentEntity(someEntity.getClass());
    …
  }
}
```